# Align 2 buttons at bottom of screen vertically

Tags: android, xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/up"
    android:text="@string/up1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/down"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:text="@string/down1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Here's my code and I want the down button to be on the very bottom. As you can see I have a align parent bottom.whenever I try to align my up button on top of that it centers both buttons on the screen which I don't want. How can I do this. Remember that I want both buttons on top of each other at the bottom of the screen. Sorry for asking a noob question.

Comment: OK so I realised that I was being stupid. First time with XML and that completely flew over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:gravity="center"` from your relative layout and try.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the RelativeLayout, and it should work

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one paste below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/up1" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/down1" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Gravity is not work well for relative layout as the name indicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/up"
    android:text="@string/up1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weight="1"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:text="@string/down1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weight="1"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/up1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/down1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yor have to take a LinearLayout and give  android:gravity="bottom"